# Ext.ModelManager.getModel has been deprecated in extjs 5

Tags: javascript, extjs, model-view-controller, extjs4, extjs5

I am `upgrading my extjs 4.2 app to extjs 5.1` .

In `ExtJs 4.2`, I have code for creating `dynamic module`, but

> in `ExtJs 5.1 Ext.ModelManager.getModel has been deprecated` and as
>   per ExtJs 5.1 docs it saying use `Ext.data.schema.Schema` instead.

I try using `Ext.data.schema.Schema.lookupEntity("DynamicModel")`, but it throws error saying

**[E] Ext.data.schema.Schema.lookupEntity(): No such Entity "DynamicModel".**

How can I get any model object in ExtJs 5 ?

How can I achieve replacement for getModel() method in extjs 5.1 , Please find my code bellow,

```
if (!Ext.ModelManager.getModel('DynamicModel')){
    Ext.define('DynamicModel', {
       extend: 'Ext.data.Model',
       idProperty : uniqueIdProperty,
       fields: fields
    });
} else {
    Ext.ModelManager.getModel('DynamicModel').setFields(fields);
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to check that your model has already been created then you can use [isCreated](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/5.1/5.1.0-apidocs/#!/api/Ext.ClassManager-method-isCreated) of [Ext.ClassManager](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/5.1/5.1.0-apidocs/#!/api/Ext.ClassManager)

```
Ext.ClassManager.isCreated('MyModel');
```

If it returns true then you can do

```
Ext.ClassManager.get('MyModel')
```

Using Schema: [Fiddle](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/nkj)

```
if(!Ext.data.schema.Schema.instances.default.hasEntity('MyModel')){ // a default schema instance is created by default
            Ext.define('MyApp.models.MyModel', {
               extend: 'MyApp.models.Base',
               fields: [{name: 'field'}]  
            });
        } else {
            Ext.data.schema.Schema.instances.default.getEntity('MyModel');// returns the constructor MyApp.models.MyModel()
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you run into issues with the above syntax, as I did, because 'default' is a reserved word, you can use the following syntax:

```
if (!Ext.data.schema.Schema.instances['default'].getEntity('MyModel')) {
    ...
}
```

IDK why Sencha is using reserved words for properties, but...oh well...